# how to set colorswatches in quickview magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i have using magento 1.9.0 and have a mango color swatches plugin
i my magento quick view a color swatches not work but another page like product page and product view page and category page it works how can i solve it please help me.

i have using porto theme and already installed lots plugin is this there issue please guide me and helping to solve this questions

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

i have found they solution of about my question..after working on my own exprience i have found a issue ..in my mango colorswatches plugin they have a inbuild file called category_media not extetly this name and after i have opened my qucikview media file in template/your theme/quickview/page../media.pthml i have replaced this file to plugin category media file and now my colorswatch works in quickview